# is it normal to create helpdesk webpart system using asp.net in sharepoint portal?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I need to create Help-desk System in SharePoint Portal. I can create it in asp.net, and then convert it to webpart. But this way restricts using of such things as workflow and other sharepoint tools. Could such method to be alive?